# How to stop Safari clipping fractions of time off audio on second play

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So it turns out, when you use javascript to trigger audio. In the latest version of safari, if you use `obj.play()` twice, the second time, the part of the audio is cut off (on mac at least).  This problem does not occur in Chrome. Only on Safari.

Is anyone aware of a work around for this?

```
<a href="javascript:playWord()">Play</a>
<audio id="t" src="https://biblicaltext.com/audio/%e1%bc%a4.mp3"></audio>
<script>
function playWord(word) {
    a = document.getElementById('t');
    //a.currentTime = 0
    a.play();
    //a.src = a.src
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fbt7rgc/1/

Redownloading the file using `a.src = a.src` works, but it is not ideal.

Comment: has the file to be hosted by biblicaltext.com or can you host it somewhere same-origin? Or will the code be ran from biblicaltext.com origin?

Comment: @Kaiido I chose to link to the exact original file in case it mattered somehow. (I wasn't sure). To be clear, the code comes from a site that is same origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a bug they should be [made aware of](https://bugs.webkit.org/).

For the time being, if you have access to the file you play in a same-origin way, you can use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and its [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) interface to play your media with high precision and less latency than through HTMLMediaElements:

```js
(async () => {
  const ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  // Using a different file because biblicaltext.com
  // doesn't allow cross-origin requests
  const data_buf = await fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3")
    .then( resp => resp.arrayBuffer() );
  const audio_buf = await ctx.decodeAudioData(data_buf);

  document.querySelector("a").onclick = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const source = ctx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audio_buf;
    source.connect(ctx.destination);
    source.start(0);
  }
})();
```

```html
<!-- Promising decodeAudioData for old Safari https://github.com/mohayonao/promise-decode-audio-data/ [MIT] -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mohayonao/promise-decode-audio-data/eb4b1322/build/promise-decode-audio-data.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Play</a>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was not aware of the Web Audio API, (I am no Javascript expert), but that looks promising. It appears to have no I.E. support at all but it might be possible to do a fallback. Im testing this out now.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in Safari, a year later. Did anyone ever report this bug? Also, would it be possible to get some instructions on how to utilize this solution, for someone who has no idea what any of the things mentioned are?