# Safari 14 (macOS). An аudio is truncated at the beginning when repeating

Tags: javascript, audio, safari

There is an audio tag on a page:

```
<audio id="audio-file-75" onplay="audioPlaying()" onended="audioEnded()" src="https://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/ey223/75.mp3"></audio>
```

Users can click on the respective audio icon to play the audio.

Everything is OK when first time playing.
But next times the аudio is truncated at the beginning (about a second).

I've tried to debug it in a Safari browser console.
The `currentTime` attribute value after the first playing isn't `0`.
I've tried to set this value to `0` and the value has been set successfully.
But if I try to play this audio again - the аudio is still truncated at the beginning.

Please, help.

Example of this issue: https://codepen.io/1d63175f-6532-4fe0-8fb6-48aeb1be1226/pen/LYyNapm

Note #1.
I didn't see this issue in Safari 13.

Note #2.
There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629761/how-to-stop-safari-clipping-fractions-of-time-off-audio-on-second-play)  of using a Web Audio API and its AudioBufferSourceNode to play media, but it doesn't work in my case, 'cause there are pretty many audio files on the page, and pre-buffering them all will cause huge performance issues.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can experience the bug for ourselfs.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, I've added an example in Codepen.

Comment: The question has been closed as a duplicate, but I'm still looking for a solution that works for me.